# android push notification not working appcelerator

Tags: android, push-notification, appcelerator, titanium-mobile

For 2 days before push notification on android are working fine. recently it is not working.
I have checked in https://platform.axway.com console push notification receives in the console but in app it does not shows any notification. It works fine in iOS.

Comment: this sounds like you need to contact support, no one here can look into your platform to help you out

Comment: We are seeing the same issue, raising a support ticket.